# iOS cocos2D Chipmunk Body's velocity is invalid

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, chipmunk, spritebuilder

In cocos2d-spritebuilder 3.4 I've create my physicworld and my player like many of the official examples.

```
    self.sprite.physicsBody = [CCPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:10 andCenter:self.anchorPoint];
    self.sprite.physicsBody.type = CCPhysicsBodyTypeDynamic;
etc...
```

So, when I try to move my sprite to the right for example with

```
[self.sprite.physicsBody applyImpulse: CGPointMake(32,0)];
```

my app going in crash reporting this:

```
Aborting due to Chipmunk error: Body's velocity is invalid.
    Failed condition: v.x == v.x && v.y == v.y
    Source:.../Source/libs/cocos2d-iphone/external/Chipmunk/src/cpBody.c:106
```

Chipmunk source's have:

```
-(void)applyImpulse:(CGPoint)impulse { _body.velocity = cpvadd(_body.velocity, cpvmult(CCP_TO_CPV(impulse), 1.0f/_body.mass));}
```

So, I knew MASS was setted by default to 1.0f, but I want to try to set this value by hand..) :

```
self.sprite.physicsBody.mass = 1.0f
```

Same error, same results...
But if I try to set:

```
self.sprite.physicsBody.body.mass = 1.0f
```

It work great.
So, what's the differences btw these two parameters?
Why applyImpulse take only body.mass?

Comment: While I am no physicist, it's clear that you are confusing velocity with impulse (given you've used velocity in your `applyImpulse` call).  I expect you will need to experiment with different values of impulse until the body starts behaving as you'd expect (possibly changing the impulse values over time, based on user behaviour).  Start by reading [this](http://www.physicsclassroom.com/class/momentum/Lesson-1/Momentum-and-Impulse-Connection).

Comment: Sir, the problem isnt the impulse. Game work well, my question is clear and refeer to chipmunk sources, about two variables of mass instead of one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, Chipmunk doesn't play nice when applying a "big" impulse. What you should try and do is build up velocity over several frames.

Edit: Check this link http://forum.cocos2d-swift.org/t/ccphysics-applyimpulse-not-working/12151/12

Comment: Thanks for you answer , but it's also recommended to dont work with velocity values if you dont want to have problems like "tunneling" during collisions detects. So, what is the right way?

Comment: That is why one should build up velocity over several frames, to avoid tunneling and going through "thin" colliders.

I do not think there is a recommended way to do it because even though the API comes with ApplyImpulse, it's not recommended nor realistic (which is why we use a physics library) to apply a big impulse without easing into it.

In my game I had to accelerate my character over several frames in order for him not to pass through walls.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks younesouhbi but despite all these precautions (i've already tried it) unfortunately Chipmunk dont use CCD (continuous collision detection) so it's impossible to avoid tunneling issue,also with build up velocity over several frames (in fact it's a structural problem derived by the physic engine...). But this is OT, my question was directed to body.mass and mass parameters..